# Can separate java .war applications within an application container use mutual app server resources?

Tags: jboss, weblogic, application-server, war

If I deploy many java .war/.jar applications inside an application server (JBoss, WebLogic, etc.) can they all use the same e.g. database pools of the application server, or does every app need its own? Are there other restrictions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all applications can share the application server database connection pools. Doing so requires less configuration, less server resources and providers better overall performance.